# Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/sass/app.scss. Laravel:10.6.2, while installing new project with php artisan auth:ui

Tags: laravel, manifest, vite, laravel-artisan, laravel-authentication

I have installed new Laravel project current version 10.6.2 with basic AUTH scaffolding  with php artisan auth:ui, it created with vite installation successfully. but when I run the project it showing me an error "Unable to locate file in Vite manifest: resources/sass/app.scss."
[vite configurations for auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u88rJ.png)

i have checked twice and also try to create file manually

1. manifest
2. vite.config.js
3. resources directory

delete vender n update composer

npm install --save-dev vite laravel-vite-plugin
npm install --save-dev @vitejs/plugin-vue    ( also try sass,bootstrap => this cause error)

at last npm run build again n again after every try.

Answer (score 0):

To install and compile vite package in a correct way without any problems you need to do these steps:

1- Install node.js ( in case: you have already installed it,just go to the terminal inside your project and give it the order:

```
  node -v
```

,and if it could give the number of version, that means: done).

2- Install npm on your device( Don't worry: if you have successfully installed node.js, It would be installed with node, and to test that type in the terminal that order:

```
  npm -v
```

,and if it could give the number of version, that means: done).

3- Now you need to get started using Vite and the Laravel plugin by giving the next order in terminal:

```
  npm install  , or just:  npm i
```

and give it few seconds till it gives you a message saying it has successfully installed, after that go and open the file vite.config.js and Make sure that the file includes:
2 codes for import & 1 code for export
like this:

```
 import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
 import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

 export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

4- Within this step you will include the vite package in your view file like
home.blade.php in the head of the html codes

```
 <!doctype html>
 <head>
 {{-- ... --}}

 @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
 </head>
```

5- In the end you need to run your npm with these orders in the terminal:

```
 npm run dev

 npm run build
```

Remember: You'll need to do the last step every time you run and open you project in the browser

Have a nice day and Good Luck.

Comment: Amira, I appreciate you, but i already have tried everything but it shows same error